# How to calculate power of a tensor field in maple?

Tags: maple

Let $\alpha_i$ be linearly independent $1$-forms and $T$ a $(1,1)$-tensor such that
$$T=T^i_j \alpha_i\otimes X^j,$$
where $X^j$'s are vector fields dual to $\alpha_j$ in Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. Then

> How to calculate $T^2=T\circ T$ in maple 2017?

Thanks.